# How can I prevent a computer on the network from accessing the LAN

Tags: dd-wrt

With dd-wrt, can I give a computer on the network access to Internet, but prevent it from accessing anything on the LAN network, including the web interface of the dd-wrt router?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is a VLAN.

Comment: Indeed a VLAN is what you need, unfortunately, most home routers do not support this.

Comment: @JeffF.though most, if not all, dd-wrt builds do

Comment: Thanks. The computer in question is actually a VPN client, that is given a fixed IP when it connects. Is this a problem for VLAN, i.e. does it require it to be a physical computer?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem that it is a VPN client. If you are running VPN server on the router, you can just set up different local subnet for the VPN clients than the physical machines on the network. Regardless of whether it is different or the same subnet, you can also add some firewall (iptables) rules to dd-wrt to restrict the access of that machine to the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Josh](https://superuser.com/users/128794/josh) and [Jeff F.](https://superuser.com/users/48096/jeff-f) mentioned, you will be able to limit access to LAN, but still allow access to the internet, once you configure a VLAN.